# Adding text to an existing text element. Selecting by class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to add text to an existing HTML that I am getting returned to by an API.

I am having issues with figuring out how can I add text to the existing text if there are no ids involved. For example here is the HTML:

```
<g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels" data-z-index="7" aria-hidden="true">
<text x="159.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">0-4</text>
<text x="333.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">5-9</text>
<text x="508.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">10-19</text>
<text x="682.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">20-99</text>
<text x="857.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">100-499</text>
<text x="1031.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">500+</text></g>
```

I'd like to add the word `Sales` after each of the number ranges. For example:

`0-4 Sales 5-9 Sales 10-19 Sales 20-99 Sales 100-499 Sales 500+ Sales`

I've attempted doing so by doing a `document.querySelector('.highcharts-axis-labels');` and editing the innerHTML but that changes the entire text. Is it possible to just add `Sales` at the end of the number range without removing the number range?

Here is a code example:

```js
  let hilables = document.querySelector('.highcharts-axis-labels');
  hilables.innerHTML = "Sales"
  console.log(hilables.innerHTML)
```

```html
<g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels" data-z-index="7" aria-hidden="true">
<text x="159.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">0-4</text>
<text x="333.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">5-9</text>
<text x="508.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">10-19</text>
<text x="682.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">20-99</text>
<text x="857.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">100-499</text>
<text x="1031.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">500+</text></g>
```

Comment: is this your highchart? if so it is probably more straighforward to refactor the data you're passing to it in the first place

Comment: I am importing it from a 3rd party so I'm unable to directly edit the chart so I'm trying to do it using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Loop through children elements of `hilables` for each one added your content *Sales*

```html
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels" data-z-index="7" aria-hidden="true">
    <text x="159.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">0-4</text>
    <text x="333.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">5-9</text>
    <text x="508.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">10-19</text>
    <text x="682.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">20-99</text>
    <text x="857.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">100-499</text>
    <text x="1031.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">500+</text></g>
    </BODY>
    <SCRIPT>
        let hilables = document.querySelector('.highcharts-axis-labels');
        [...hilables.children].forEach(hilable=>hilable.innerText += ' Sales')
    </SCRIPT>   
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do that With CSS by selecting all `text` elements of specific class `.highcharts-axis-labels` and with `:after` and `content` insert your word want to add * Sales*

```html
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels" data-z-index="7" aria-hidden="true">
    <text x="159.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">0-4</text>
    <text x="333.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">5-9</text>
    <text x="508.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">10-19</text>
    <text x="682.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">20-99</text>
    <text x="857.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">100-499</text>
    <text x="1031.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">500+</text></g>
    </BODY> 
    <STYLE>
        .highcharts-axis-labels text:after {
            content: ' Sales';
        }
    </STYLE>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```js
var hilables1 = document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-axis-labels1');
for (var i = hilables1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
hilables1[i].innerText = hilables1[i].innerText + " Sales";
}
```

```html
<g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels" data-z-index="7" aria-hidden="true">
<text class="highcharts-axis-labels1" x="159.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">0-4</text>
<text class="highcharts-axis-labels1"x="333.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">5-9</text>
<text class="highcharts-axis-labels1"x="508.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">10-19</text>
<text class="highcharts-axis-labels1"x="682.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">20-99</text>
<text class="highcharts-axis-labels1"x="857.25" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">100-499</text>
<text class="highcharts-axis-labels1" x="1031.75" style="color:#11111;cursor:default;font-size:10px;font-family:roboto;font-weight:700;text-shadow:false;fill:#11111;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="307" opacity="1">500+</text></g>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
hilables.innerHTML = "Sales";
```

You should put

```
 hilables.innerHTML += " Sales";
```

this appends "Sales" string to the end of the innerHTML.